# AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter keeps disconnecting on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, asus

I bought a new laptop Asus X540LA it has this wireless card `AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter` but it keeps disconnecting randomly when using it, please help.

I will attach the last 100 lines of my `/var/log/kern.log`.

[last 100 lines of my kernel log file](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23224429/)

[my wireless card info](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23224435/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same card. Changing the wifi bandwidth on my router from 40mhz to 20mhz fixed the issue for me.

Comment: thanks, I think I do not need as it is working now very well.